# Add a printer in command prompt to a local port

Tags: windows, printing, command-line

I want to add a printer with my custom driver to a local port and not a printer port. I tried the following command
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "Test Printer" /f g:\Backup\queueASP\custom.INF /r "PrintDriver:" /m "ASPSample(Optra L Plus PS)"
But it says the port is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

/F should be used with a UNC path :

> /F[file] Specifies the UNC path and name of a .inf file that the .inf
>   file specified with /f[file] depends on.

Try keeping the INF file under %windir%\inf\

Comment: Thank you for your reply /f g:\Backup\queueASP\custom.INF worked fine. But it was the port name which was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The driver name has to be exactly the same, the default ports have a colon at the end of their names. The examples I viewed had this colon so it was my fault that the port was a custom port and it was not having a colon at the end.
"So make sure that the driver name is exact"